# How to load a self-hosted font in React and Material Ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, font-face

I'm trying to load a self hosted font in a react project. I'm running it under development mode (`npm run start`) and not in production. I've followed the [instructions](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/) on the official site of Material UI but had no success. My fonts are stored in `path/to/react-project/src/fonts` folder. This is an ecxerpt of my code:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import ProximaNovaReg from '../fonts/Proxima-Nova-Reg.ttf';
import ProximaNovaIt from '../fonts/Proxima-Nova-It.otf';
import ProximaNovaBold from '../fonts/Proxima-Nova-Bold.otf';
import FuturaBold from '../fonts/Futura-Bold.ttf';


const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: [
      'Proxima-Nova',
      'sans-serif',
    ].join(','),
  },
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Proxima-Nova';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(${ProximaNovaReg}) format('truetype')
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Proxima-Nova';
          font-style: italic;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(${ProximaNovaIt}) format('otf')
        }
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Proxima-Nova';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 700;
          src: url(${ProximaNovaBold}) format('otf')
        }
        @font-face {
          fontFamily: 'Futura';
          fontStyle: 'normal';
          fontDisplay: 'swap';
          fontWeight: 700;
          src: url(${FuturaBold}) format('truetype')
        }
      `,
    },
  },
});

// ...
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Box
      sx={{
        fontFamily: 'Proxima-Nova',
      }}
    >
      Proxima-Nova
    </Box>
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

**package.json:** "@mui/material": "^5.10.1"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from docs ".

⚠️ This requires that you have a plugin or loader in your build process that can handle loading ttf, woff, and woff2 files. Fonts will not be embedded within your bundle. They will be loaded from your webserver instead of a CDN." What do you use as build process?

Comment: I still don't use the fonts in production mode. Anyway I plan to use `file-loader`.